# Ignore errors in JNI C++ code, eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, java-native-interface

Hi I'm using JNI in android, eclipse.

To start with, I tried to run a demo in OpenCV using JNI. Even though the program compiles and runs in my Android Phone, when I opened the C codes in JNI folder out of curiosity, the project shows countless errors in that file and the project will never compile anymore.

I think it is because eclipse cannot parse the C codes correctly, nevertheless the JNI utilities can handle them.

So is there a way to suppress these errors in IDE to make it compile?

(I tag android in expectation that these problems be frequent in android development.)

### update

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Sample - face-detection ****

G:\progWorkSpace\Android\Tegra\tadp_download\android-ndk-r8d-windows\android-ndk-r8d\ndk-build.cmd 
Install        : libdetection_based_tracker.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libdetection_based_tracker.so

**** Build Finished ****
```

The CDT builds successfully.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If no compile or link error is show in the CDT build console(not int the problems view), you can just delete the errors in the problems list and the application can run. If there are errors shown in the CDT build console, well, paste them here.

Comment: It builds in the CDT. And I'll try out your solution. Thx

Comment: You may need add the opencv include path manually, ADT seems to be unable to add them automatically. So the IDE cannot locate the header files you include, even though ndk-build can locate them. But even you do so, eclipse will still give weird error messages from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well the first time I opened a c++ file in eclipse.  I quit eclipse and relaunched it which for some reason fixed the problem.